# how to make android system app that use jni to open /dev/video* or other system file?

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-source, android.mk

i have an android develpment board NanoPi-M4,with android 8.1 aosp source tree.i am trying make an app that can access usb camera use v4l api from jni(for some reason,not use android camera api).

PS: i do not want use `su` method or `chmod` command change file permission,i just want my app running like other system app from aosp.

my app already put in to aosp source tree.with some permission setting:

Android.mk from my app:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
            $(call all-subdir-java-files)

LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME := MyVideoTest

LOCAL_SDK_VERSION := current
LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := platform
LOCAL_PRIVILEGED_MODULE := true
LOCAL_PROGUARD_ENABLED := disabled

include $(BUILD_PACKAGE)

#jni
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
include $(call all-makefiles-under,$(LOCAL_PATH))
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.test.myvideo" coreApp="true" android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system"
    >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
  
    <application android:label="MyVideoTest">

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"  android:label="MyVideoTest">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

then, at jni code,just try open /dev/video* file:

```
std::string tryopen(std::string str)
{
    auto fd = open(str.c_str(), O_RDWR, 0);
    if (fd >= 0)
    {
        return "ok:" + str + ",  ";
    }
    else
    {
        return "fail:" + str + ",m:" + strerror(errno) + ",   ";
    }
}

jstring test(JNIEnv* env, jclass clazz)
{

    std::string str = "";
    str += tryopen("/dev/video0");
    str += tryopen("/dev/video1");
    str += tryopen("/dev/video2");
    str += tryopen("/dev/video3");

    return env->NewStringUTF(str.c_str());
}
```

also,modify `frameworks/base/data/etc/platform.xml` file ,add line:
`<system-user-whitelisted-app package="com.test.myvideo" />`

after run app,i got error message:  Permission denied
and use ps -A check my app,it's already become system user:

```
system        3261   411 4480832 105024 0                   0 S com.test.myvideo
```

---

after more search and research,i figure out these infomation:

1, LOCAL_PRIVILEGED_MODULE make app have more power,but limited in java runtime
2, system != root ,system uid is not root user,so is not max power user.
3, /dev/video* have linux permission 0660,and is belong media user,so system user can not read it.

then,i found a file in aosp: ueventd.rc,i am add these line in this file:

```
/dev/video0          0666   media      camera
/dev/video1          0666   media      camera
/dev/video2          0666   media      camera
```

change 0660 to 0666 ,then,my app can read it.

---

more solution are still welcome. because i think ueventd.rc break android secure system.

Comment: Please check if you can add commands to change the file permissions in your device's init.rc file (eg: `device/linaro/hikey/init.common.rc`), like it is done in [here](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:device/linaro/hikey/init.common.rc;l=37?q=%22chmod%200666%20%2Fdev%22).